# How to change the CSS of one image when hovering another image?

Tags: html, css, image, opacity, fade

So I'm tyring to fade one image in and the other out when hovered using html/css.
These images sit on top of each other.  One is a transparent play button (which has to be on top?) And the other is a picture.  When hovered, I want the play button to fade in and the picture to fade out.

I have done countless research and here is what I currently have:

```
<div id="videocontainer">
  <a href="#"><img class="playButton" onclick="do something" src="imagesrc" alt="" /></a>
  <img class = "vidImage" src="imagesrc" alt=""/>
</div>
```

And here is my css

```
    #videocontainer
    {
      position: relative;   
      width: 760px; 
      height:400px;
    }

    .playButton
    {
      z-index: 500;
      position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
      width:760px;
      height:400px; 
    }

    .vidImage
    {
       position: relative; 
       top: 0; 
       left: 0;
    }

   .playButton:hover ~ .vidImage
   {
     -webkit-opacity: 0.25;
     -moz-opacity: 0.25;
     opacity: 0.25;
     -webkit-transition: all 3s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 3s ease;
     -ms-transition: all 3s ease;
     -o-transition: all 3s ease;
      transition: all 3s ease
   }


   .playButton:hover 
   {
     -webkit-opacity: 0.25;
     -moz-opacity: 0.25;
     opacity: 0.25;
     -webkit-transition: all 3s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 3s ease;
     -ms-transition: all 3s ease;
     -o-transition: all 3s ease;
      transition: all 3s ease;
   }
```

This should fade both the image and the play button when the play button is hovered.  But it is only fading out the play button and nothing is happening to the vidimage.  Is it possible that because the transparent play button is a little bigger than the video image, that its not affecting it at all because its covering it?  Most of my research tells me to use ~ or + in my CSS but none have worked for me.  Thanks for the help.

Here is a link to what I currently am working with: http://webdesignog.com

Comment: Is using jquery an option? It contains existing methods for hover/click cross fades on objects.

Comment: I would prefer not digging into jQuery and implementing it into each post.  But if its the last resort then I'll try it.

Comment: You can't do that with CSS, if you want to keep your current HTML markup.

Comment: You can also check http://theberrics.com/dailyops for a working example

Comment: He used a lot of jQuery in that example.

Comment: Really?  Cuz I've read lots of examples of when one element is hovered, anothers css is changed.  All seemed to work and people agreed.  Just didn't work for me :(

Comment: That **will** work with CSS, but you must learn about CSS selectors. `Adjacent sibling selectors have the following syntax: E1 + E2, where E2 is the subject of the selector. The selector matches if E1 and E2 share the same parent in the document tree and E1 immediately precedes E2, ignoring non-element nodes (such as text nodes and comments)`. An your classes do not have same parent. Also you should know that CSS selectors **can't** match preceding elements.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest tweaking what you have.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
   <img src="play.jpg" alt="Play Image" class="play" />
   <img src="picture.jpg" alt="Picture Image" class="picture" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   position: relative;
}

#container IMG {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   -webkit-transition: all 3s ease;
   -moz-transition: all 3s ease;
   -ms-transition: all 3s ease;
   -o-transition: all 3s ease;
   transition: all 3s ease;
}

#container IMG.play {
   opacity: 1;
}

#container IMG.picture {
   opacity: 0;
}

#container:hover IMG.play {
   opacity: 0;
}

#container:hover IMG.picture {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

When you hover over the container, one of the images fades in and the other fades out. You should be able to wrap anything in anchors if you need to.

Comment: Thanks.  This is very close to what I want but still not it.  This code currently shows the only the play button.  When hovered, it then fads the play button out and the picture image in.

Comment: I need that reversed which I did by changing the css opacity values.  But what I actually need is for both the image and play button to be displayed at once.   Then once hovered, the picture fades out almost all the way but not completetely and the play button fades in completeely

Comment: Nevermind.  Everything is fixed now.  I simple just added a z-index to the play button and used opacity 0.25 to have them not fade completely.  Thanks again!

Comment: Doesn't makes sence at all, try using jQ

Answer (score 0):

Do not apply the `.hover` effect on your `<img class="playButton">` but on the `<a>` tag that surronds it. Your img is not seen like an image but like a link (because it is IN the `<a>` tag and it is like hidden by it). You should always take the more external selector.